# Disabled SSL on SQL Server, now connection fails

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, poodle-attack

I have a customer that is worried about the [latest SSL vulnerability](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/10/ssl-broken-again-in-poodle-attack/) POODLE. They have a utility ([IIS Crypto 1.4](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx)) that disables SSL 2.0-3.0 on the servers they run it on. They have disabled SSL on both the server my service is running and the remote SQL Server. The SQL connection string is pretty standard:

```
Server=myServerIPAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

When my service starts it tries to perform a Linq to SQL query and gets the error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

If they re-enable SSL on the SQL Server it works fine. My program is a Windows Service built on .NET 3.5. What is the cause of this error, and where can I make adjustments so my service will run?

Comment: I am inclinced to close that in favour of dumping it to serverfault.com - this is not a programming question, it is one about generic system administration. Alternatively dba.stackexchange.com - for database specific questions. As Poodle is a major pain point dba.stackexchange.com may be the best place.

Comment: but they say only my program has issues, all others work fine.  So I don't know if its something wrong with me, or if it really is a DB setting.

Comment: close it, ill post on dba.stackexchange.

Comment: Does your ConnectionString use the Encrypt=true keyword? If so that might be the source of the issue.

Comment: It definitely is not a program level but a config thing (which btw., includes the connection string) and someone specialized in this may be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

See if your windows service code has any line like this in it:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

That would limit the protocol to ssl3 which has now been disabled, which leads to this type of error.